# inapp browser is not working on iphone s6

Tags: android, ios, ionic3, inappbrowser

I have used the following code to open the link

```
const browser = this.iab.create(this.buttonAttr,'_self',{ hardwareback:'yes',hideurlbar:'yes'});

       browser.show();

       //Events: loadstart, loadstop, loaderror, exit
       browser.on('exit').subscribe(() => {
           //Do whatever here
       }, err => {
           console.log(err);
       });
```

its working good on android.

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you share what's happening on your iPhone and or an actual error message?

Comment: it does not shows any error message. it does not opening.